# How to position Highcharts tooltip on top of bar or at 0 line of Y-axis for negative value

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Highcharts tooltip is shown at bottom of the column bar for negative values but i want it to show on top or at 0 axis level. Please help.

Present tooltip position as per highcharts:
[image: Present tooltip position as per highcharts]

Reference image of how i want to position:
[image: Reference image of how i want to position]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the positioner of tooltip like this

```
   tooltip: {
        positioner: function(__, __, point) {
        return {
          x: point.plotX,
          y: point.negative ? point.plotY - point.h : point.plotY
        }
      }
    }
```